# Devolver Objeto C# por AJAX (Json - ASP.NET - MVC 5)

Tags: c#, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-5

Me encuentro trabajando en una aplicación la cual contiene un tablero 'Kanban' (Algunos sabrán de qué se trata). Estoy intentando devolver un objeto C#, el cual contiene otros objetos (Que serían las tareas que el usuario tiene creadas en ese tablero). Lo que quiero hacer es que al momento de devolver los datos a la vista, esté solo me liste el campo 'Tarea' de cada uno de esos objetos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la forma en que estoy devolviendo los datos y me funciona. Pero como pueden ver la parte que tengo comentada es lo que no me funciona, supongo porque debo hacerle algún tipo de conversión a ese objeto 'kanban'.

﻿[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Que debo hacer o como me pueden ayudar?

Gracias

Comment: por favor vuelve a leer [ask]. El codigo debe ir como texto y no como imagenes.

Comment: pero esta comentado como te va a funcionar algo comentado, ademas que es lo que no funciona?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quiere devolver solo las tareas usarias

```
resultadoKanban = kanban.Select(x=>x.Tarea).ToList()
```

la idea es solo tomar esa propeidad para tener la lista

Comment: buenas pudieramos ir a chat para conversar tengo algunas dudas.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83071/consultac

Comment: Muchas gracias Leandro, me funciono. ¿De pronto me podrias ayudar con algo sencillo y es como tomar ese array en la vista y por medio de algun bucle, me imprima la lista?